# Can i store jQuery events in a variable?

Tags: jquery

I want to store two or more events in a variable like element-selectors.
or - Is there any another way to do that? let me know.

The way I know:

```js
let del = $('.delete');
let auto = $('.auto');
let show = $('.show');

del.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(function() {
  auto.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(function() {
    show.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="display: none" class="delete">delete</div>
<div style="display: none" class="auto">auto</div>
<div style="display: none" class="show">show</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I want something like this:

```
let envent = fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(); 

del.envent {
  auto.envent {
    show.envent;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by writing a reusable function:

```
function mySequence(el, callback) {
    return el.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(callback);
}
```

Then to use it, you pass `del` into it:

```
mySequence(del, function() {
    // Do the next thing
});
```

Live Example (with shorter delay):

```js
function mySequence(el, callback) {
    return el.fadeIn().delay(300).fadeOut(callback);
}

let del = $('.delete');
let auto = $('.auto');
let show = $('.show');

mySequence(del, function() {
    mySequence(auto, function() {
        mySequence(show);
    });
});
```

```html
<div style="display: none" class="delete">delete</div>
<div style="display: none" class="auto">auto</div>
<div style="display: none" class="show">show</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do a little jQuery plugin if you like:

```
$.fn.mySequence = function(callback) {
    return this.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(callback);
};
```

Then to use it, you use it like any other jQuery function:

```
del.mySequence(function() {
    // Do the next thing
});
```

Live Example (with shorter delay):

```js
$.fn.mySequence = function(callback) {
    return this.fadeIn().delay(300).fadeOut(callback);
};

let del = $('.delete');
let auto = $('.auto');
let show = $('.show');

del.mySequence(function() {
    auto.mySequence(function() {
        show.mySequence();
    });
});
```

```html
<div style="display: none" class="delete">delete</div>
<div style="display: none" class="auto">auto</div>
<div style="display: none" class="show">show</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to avoid directly passing callbacks in, you could use native Promises or jQuery's `Deferred` object. Here's a plugin that returns a `Deferred`'s promise:

```
$.fn.mySequence = function() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    this.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(d.resolve.bind(d));
    return d.promise();
};
```

Then to use it, you use it like any other jQuery function:

```
del.mySequence()
.then(function() {
    // Do the next thing
});
```

Live Example (with shorter delay):

```js
$.fn.mySequence = function() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    this.fadeIn().delay(300).fadeOut(d.resolve.bind(d));
    return d.promise();
};

let del = $('.delete');
let auto = $('.auto');
let show = $('.show');

del.mySequence()
.then(function() {
    return auto.mySequence();
})
.then(function() {
    return show.mySequence();
});
```

```html
<div style="display: none" class="delete">delete</div>
<div style="display: none" class="auto">auto</div>
<div style="display: none" class="show">show</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```js
const list = $("#container").children();
let cnt = 0;
const fader = () => { 
  if (cnt>=list.length) return; 
  $(list[cnt]).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(fader); cnt++;
};
fader();
```

```css
.fade { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="delete fade">Del</div>
  <div class="auto fade">Auto</div>
  <div class="show fade">Show</div>
</div>
```